# How could i download Mariabd 10.2 in Debian 9?

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

apt-get install mariadb-server installs 10.1 version. However i want the latest version. How could i do that? I have checked apt sources and they are allright.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the latest of any package in Linux you have two options, either you change the repository from stable to unstable or you compile from source

Comment: According to mariadb, version 10.2 is stable... 10.3 is beta

Comment: this will help you https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/upgrading-from-mariadb-101-to-mariadb-102